# Ever since he was unemployed, he's been looking for a new job

Tags: grammar

Does this sentence contradict itself?

> Ever since he was unemployed, he's been looking for a new job.

If he is still looking for a new job, that means he is still unemployed. But the sentence indicates he *was* unemployed.

So, in order to make the sentence correct, I think I should change it to

> Ever since he's been unemployed, he's been looking for a new job.

Answer (score 2):

> Ever since he was unemployed, ...

In the structure [ *"ever since + X"* ], X is a moment or an event. But being unemployed is a state, which is neither a moment nor an event, so this is semantically invalid.

Another way to interpret this clause is that "*was unemployed*" is the passive form of the verb "unemploy", as in, "*Someone unemployed him*". But there is no such verb in English.

> Ever since he's been unemployed, he's been looking for a new job.

This sentence is somewhat better in the present tense, but again, "being unemployed" is not an event or a moment when something can start, so it's ungrammatical.

Consider one of these instead:

> Ever since *he became unemployed*, ...
> Ever since *he lost his job/got fired/got laid off*, ...
> Ever since *his termination*, ...

Comment: This starts off as a good answer. However I disagree so far as "been unemployed" is concerned. Whilst it is a state rather than an event it is certainly grammatical to use "been + adjective 1" in relation to "been + adjective 2" eg. *Ever since I've been rich I've been happy*.  It is even idiomatic to use it where it is followed by a non-stative action eg *Ever since she's been ill, she has seen the doctor every Tuesday*.

Comment: Can you tell me what the adjective 1 and 2 are, please?

Comment: @Stephen They can be anything - the distinction between 1 and 2 is that they are different. *Ever since I've been wearing glasses I've been noticing what you look like*. - *...been ruuning...I've been tired* etc.

Comment: Thanks @WS2. I see your point about it being technically grammatical, so I've changed my answer to state it's "semantically invalid" instead. To my Canadian ear, your examples about being rich and ill are wrong and not idiomatic. They should use "*got/became rich/ill*" to sound right.

Comment: @gotube: What if I remove the word "ever": *since he's been unemployed, he's been looking for a new job.* I think it works. On the contrary, *since he was unemployed, he's been looking for a new job* does not work, because it's self contradictory. Do you think so?

Comment: @Stephen I think you're right. Somehow "since X" includes the meaning of, "from the time that X began", while "ever since X" does not. Your version without "ever" sounds natural to me

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @gotube Unless of course one was using "since" in the sense of "as" - but then the tenses don't match. It would need to be *Since he was unemployed, he was looking for a job*.